# Unable to add TextView into main xml Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera, android-view

I've been working on an app and am looking to adding a text view below the Camera view so that I could display some text there.
But, for some reason when trying to drag a text view into the layout it doesn't show up on the final screen.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/topLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

  <com.google.android.CameraSourcePreview
  android:id="@+id/preview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.GraphicOverlay
    android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


  </com.google.android.CameraSourcePreview>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Thxml layout output]

Comment: Can you show your demo design?

Answer (score 1):

Layout view **com.google.android.CameraSourcePreview** height is set as 'match_parent' , so its eating up all the space on the view-port.

Try giving particular height and you should be able to see textview added below CameraSourcePreview.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Sahil, Thanks for the reply. I tried changing height to android:layout_height="700px" , but I'm still unable to add a text view into the layout. When I drag the text view into the screen, It doesn't show up. The output is similar to the image shown in my question.

Comment: 700px is large number for height, try 100 px to see if we are on right track.

Comment: hey sahil, I solved the issue by changing to frame layout as mentioned by seymur in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're not able to add the `TextView` due to there not being enough space on the screen.

You're using a `LinearLayout` which displays all of it's views one after the other in either a *vertical* or *horizontal* manner.

Your `CameraSourcePreview` has it's height and width set to `match_parent`, which means it'll stretch completely on the screen. However, in a `LinearLayout`, this also means that there's no space to place the next View because it'll be placed off the screen.

You can add `android:layout_weight="1"` to your `CameraSourcePreview`. This will allow your `TextView` to fit into the `LinearLayout` because it's basically your `CameraSourcePreview` telling others it'll resize itself to allow for other components to fit on the screen.

But if you don't want your `CameraSourcePreview` to resize itself based on other Views, then you should look into using some other Layouts instead of LinearLayout. Perhaps one such as `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout` will work better, since they allow overlapping Views on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the height of the camera view is taking the whole space on the display you can use layout_weight for LinearLayout to make some necessary space for your TextView.

Just make height of CameraSourcePreview equals to 0dp and add a property

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

So this it would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/topLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.CameraSourcePreview
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.google.android.GraphicOverlay
        android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</com.google.android.CameraSourcePreview>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some text here" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using LinearLayout I suggest to use FrameLayout which is easy to control for your case. It is also possible to display textView on CameraSourcePreview by using following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/topLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<com.google.android.CameraSourcePreview
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity ="center">
    <com.google.android.GraphicOverlay
        android:id="@+id/faceOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</com.google.android.CameraSourcePreview>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="some text here"
    android:layout_gravity ="center|bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hey Seyum, Thanks for the suggestion. This works , but I'm still curious as to why I can't see the textView in android studio, but I can view it on my phone. My android studio main layout looks like the image I've shown in my question.